# Issue with network initialization on headless Debian 11 server with USB NIC

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, systemctl

***edit***

What I did is the following (hoping it will not bite me in the bottom):

1. created an `restart_network.sh` in my `/root` dir. In it:

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! (grep -q "ttl" <<< "$(ping -c2 192.168.1.150)")
do
 ifup enx207bd2248c85
done
```

2. created `/etc/systemd/system/fixlan.service` with:

```
[Unit]

Description=Fix network incase the USB-NIC does not start.
#because I want it to first try to activate the USB-NIC alone
After=networking.service
#If didn't succeed, at least wait for network before starting all
#Nextcloud services (because it's the designation of the server)
Before=snap.nextcloud.mdns-publisher.service snap.nextcloud.redis-server.service snap.nextcloud.mysql.service snap.nextcloud.renew-certs.service snap.nextcloud.apache.service snap.nextcloud.logrotate.service snap.nextcloud.nextcloud-fixer.service snap.nextcloud.php-fpm.service

[Service]

ExecStart=/root/restart_network.sh
```

I never tried creating a systemd service, and I don't know if I am doing it right.

***edit***

I have a headless debian 11 server.
The NIC was broken so I installed a USB NIC.
Every so often (like every fifth startup or something) the NIC is not starting.
If I log in and

```
ifup enx207bd2248c85
```

the NIC obtains its IP address, then I can restart all relevant services.

So the idea is to do something like:

```
if (grep -q "ttl" <<< "$(ping -q -c2 192.168.1.151)"); then
 reboot now;
fi
```

As a startup script, which I am not quite sure how to do (the addition of a startup script).
Now this will probably work, but there is a big chance that the machine will enter a reboot loop. So, do you think there is a better way? Maybe only

```
if (grep -q "ttl" <<< "$(ping -q -c2 192.168.1.151)"); then
# restart all services
fi
```

So I am sure I don't know how to do this...

Please help.

Comment: What do you see in the logs about network init?

Comment: I am currently unable to access the machine, bu basically yesterday (not today, though) there was a `cannot find device enx207bd2248c85` in the system log, a little after mounting all drives correctly. So...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I eventually used `crontab` and added a `@reboot` line running `/root/restart_network.sh`. As mentioned, the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! (grep -q "ttl" <<< "$(ping -c2 192.168.1.150)")
do
 ifup enx207bd2248c85
 systemctl restart snap.nextcloud.* #added just in case...
done
```